# Changing the URLs in a WSDL

Tags: wcf

So, we have a service that is behind a load balancer, and we are offloading SSL at the load balancer.  The WSDL shown when we go to `https://example.com/Service.svc?wsdl` shows `http://example.com/Service.svc` and `http://example.com/Service.svc?wsdl=wsdl0`.  Is there a way to change what the WSDL shows so that all of the URLs are `https` instead of `http`?

Comment: interesting question and found something for you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2005/11/16/493496.aspx

Comment: @codebased:  Looks like that link is not for WCF (and doesn't work with WCF).